# Jquery - Help writing toggling button?

Tags: function, jquery

I am building a fly out box and am having an issue. I think it can be solved with an if / then statement but am not sure how to do it.

I have the following 8 divs that are set as buttons to click.

```
<script>
    $( "#btn1" ).click(function() {
        $( "#one" ).toggle( "slide", "easeInOutExpo", 100);
    });
    $( "#btn2" ).click(function() {
        $( "#two").toggle( "slide", "easeInOutExpo", 100);
    });
    $( "#btn3" ).click(function() {
        $( "#three" ).toggle( "slide", "easeInOutExpo", 100);
    });
    $( "#btn4" ).click(function() {
       $( "#four" ).toggle( "slide", "easeInOutExpo", 100);
    });
    $( "#btn5" ).click(function() {
        $( "#five" ).toggle( "slide", "easeInOutExpo", 100);
    });
    $( "#btn6" ).click(function() {
       $( "#six" ).toggle( "slide", "easeInOutExpo", 100);
    });
    $( "#btn7" ).click(function() {
        $( "#seven" ).toggle( "slide", "easeInOutExpo", 100);
    });
    $( "#eight" ).click(function() {
       $( "#one" ).toggle( "slide", "easeInOutExpo", 100);
    });

</script>
```

Each div works great on click. 
Here is what I need it to do:

if ANY of the other divs are open, I need those to toggle...
so say I click on 3 then click on 7, 3 should close.

Here is the html:

```
<div id="transaction">
    <div id="btn1">btn1 </div>
    <div id="btn2">btn1 </div>
    <div id="btn3">btn1 </div>
    <div id="btn4">btn1 </div>
    <div id="btn5">btn1 </div>
    <div id="btn6">btn1 </div>
    <div id="btn7">btn1 </div>
    <div id="btn8">btn1 </div>
</div>
<p id="one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque dapibus commodo purus sit amet fermentum. Donec libero quam, facilisis non consectetur vel, lacinia eu nibh. Pellentesque eget porttitor purus. Donec non quam nulla, luctus tempor urna. Duis commodo cursus justo eget pellentesque. Aliquam a aliquam odio. Donec tristique lorem vitae dolor.</p>
<p id="two">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque dapibus commodo purus sit amet fermentum. Donec libero quam, facilisis non consectetur vel, lacinia eu nibh. Pellentesque eget porttitor purus. Donec non quam nulla, luctus tempor urna. Duis commodo cursus justo eget pellentesque. Aliquam a aliquam odio. Donec tristique lorem vitae dolor.</p>
<p id="three">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque dapibus commodo purus sit amet fermentum. Donec libero quam, facilisis non consectetur vel, lacinia eu nibh. Pellentesque eget porttitor purus. Donec non quam nulla, luctus tempor urna. Duis commodo cursus justo eget pellentesque. Aliquam a aliquam odio. Donec tristique lorem vitae dolor.</p>
<p id="four">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque dapibus commodo purus sit amet fermentum. Donec libero quam, facilisis non consectetur vel, lacinia eu nibh. Pellentesque eget porttitor purus. Donec non quam nulla, luctus tempor urna. Duis commodo cursus justo eget pellentesque. Aliquam a aliquam odio. Donec tristique lorem vitae dolor.</p>
<p id="five">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque dapibus commodo purus sit amet fermentum. Donec libero quam, facilisis non consectetur vel, lacinia eu nibh. Pellentesque eget porttitor purus. Donec non quam nulla, luctus tempor urna. Duis commodo cursus justo eget pellentesque. Aliquam a aliquam odio. Donec tristique lorem vitae dolor.</p>
<p id="six">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque dapibus commodo purus sit amet fermentum. Donec libero quam, facilisis non consectetur vel, lacinia eu nibh. Pellentesque eget porttitor purus. Donec non quam nulla, luctus tempor urna. Duis commodo cursus justo eget pellentesque. Aliquam a aliquam odio. Donec tristique lorem vitae dolor.</p>
<p id="seven">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque dapibus commodo purus sit amet fermentum. Donec libero quam, facilisis non consectetur vel, lacinia eu nibh. Pellentesque eget porttitor purus. Donec non quam nulla, luctus tempor urna. Duis commodo cursus justo eget pellentesque. Aliquam a aliquam odio. Donec tristique lorem vitae dolor.</p>
<p id="seven">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque dapibus commodo purus sit amet fermentum. Donec libero quam, facilisis non consectetur vel, lacinia eu nibh. Pellentesque eget porttitor purus. Donec non quam nulla, luctus tempor urna. Duis commodo cursus justo eget pellentesque. Aliquam a aliquam odio. Donec tristique lorem vitae dolor.</p>
<script>
$( "#btn1" ).click(function() {
$( "#one" ).toggle( "slide", "easeInOutExpo", 100);
});
$( "#btn2" ).click(function() {
$( "#two").toggle( "slide", "easeInOutExpo", 100);
});
$( "#btn3" ).click(function() {
$( "#three" ).toggle( "slide", "easeInOutExpo", 100);
});
$( "#btn4" ).click(function() {
$( "#four" ).toggle( "slide", "easeInOutExpo", 100);
});
$( "#btn5" ).click(function() {
$( "#five" ).toggle( "slide", "easeInOutExpo", 100);
});
$( "#btn6" ).click(function() {
$( "#six" ).toggle( "slide", "easeInOutExpo", 100);
});
$( "#btn7" ).click(function() {
$( "#seven" ).toggle( "slide", "easeInOutExpo", 100);
});
$( "#eight" ).click(function() {
$( "#one" ).toggle( "slide", "easeInOutExpo", 100);
});

</script>
```

Comment: Can you show us your HTML? We may be able to simplify your code.

Comment: jquery, write less, do more. remember ?

Comment: From the description of your question, are you trying to do this http://jqueryui.com/accordion/?

Comment: sort of, but it's more like a "pop out" box.

Comment: @UnLoco, exactly, hence the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why classes and the [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings) method exist.

To use another button, I prefer to employ the magic of `.data()` and `data-` attributes. Add something like this to a button's HTML:

```
<div class="btn" id="btn1" data-para="one">
```

And to the paragraphs:

```
<p class="para" id="one">Lorem ipsum...</p>
```

And you can use this jQuery instead:

```
$('.btn').on('click',function(e) {
    var id = $(this).data('para');
    $('#'+id).toggle( "slide", "easeInOutExpo", 100).siblings('.para').hide();
});
```

Comment: ok so how this works is that when we click on an item we pass a hide function to the rest of the siblings? so essentially I'd have to have a ul / li construct or something similar? what about nested divs?

Comment: I think this is close. But "this" is tripping it up. When I click on 1, it should trigger div one,

Comment: Updated. This wasn't clear originally; thanks for adding the HTML.

Comment: Did you update your HTML correctly? http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/ZgKuH/ -- I'm not clear what `.toggle("slide", "easeInOutExpo", 100)` is supposed to do, so you'll have to figure that part out on your own.

Comment: thanks. I understand the siblings. Trying to understand this "    $('#'+id).toggle( "slide", "easeInOutExpo", 100).siblings('.para').hide();"

Comment: ah ok so it sets a variable to be whatever is clicked (which is attatched with para) on which is then used to toggle then the rest of the para is set to hide.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a prime candidate for event delegation: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Essentially, the idea is that you can detect which element has been clicked on, rather than using a bunch of `.on("click")` events.  This dramatically saves on performance.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jD78j/2/

Here's the code that is used:

```
$(document).on("click","button", function(e) {

    var buttonId = $(e.target).attr("id");
    var nextDiv = $("#" + buttonId).next();

    $("div").slideUp("fast");

    if(nextDiv.is(":visible")) {
        return false;
    } else {
        nextDiv.slideToggle("fast");
    }

});
```

This gives you the added benefit of actually knowing which button the user clicked through the `event` object which has a lot of different properties to play with.

Comment: yeah, that is what I was thinking but had not idea where to start.. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Deedub Sweet!  Glad I could help.  If this is what you were looking for, mark it as the right answer.

Comment: Sethen, when I click on the other button, the existing one still doesn't hide.

Comment: @Deedub I updated the code in the fiddle, works now.  It's just a simple `slideUp` for all divs.  Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @Deedub I actually updated one more time because I found a bug.  This is what you're looking for, I think.  Only one div open at a time.

Comment: Sethen thanks, sorry for being a pain, but how would this work if instead of buttons I had this as my buttons:<div class="btn" id="btn1" data-para="one" >btn1 </div>
    <div class="btn" id="btn2"  data-para="two" >btn1 </div>
    <div class="btn" id="btn3"  data-para="three" >btn1 </div>
    <div class="btn" id="btn4"  data-para="four" >btn1 </div>
    <div class="btn" id="btn5"  data-para="five" >btn1 </div>
    <div class="btn" id="btn6"  data-para="six" >btn1 </div>
    <div class="btn" id="btn7"  data-para="one" >btn1 </div>
    <div class="btn" id="btn8" >btn1 </div>